# TableModel and MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am struggling to see why this works. I have built a simple example using MVC to show a JTable that is editable and a button. The TableModel gets its data as an ArrayList supplied by the model. When a value is edited the table model updates the specific object in the ArrayList. When the user hits finish the actionlistener tells the controller finish has been hit, which calls a method in the model, finish(). All finish() does is iterate the ArrayList in a string output showing the values.

I just don't understand how AbstractTableModel updates the ArrayList in the model class. while it gets the ArrayList from the Model, it never calls a method to tell the model to update the ArrayList values. Any help would really be appreciated.

I have screenshots but I can't post them so here is the output with the default data

```
Int value: 1 String value: One
Int value: 2 String value: Two
```

And then when I change the int values to 11 and 22 in the JTable:

```
Int value: 11 String value: One
Int value: 22 String value: Two
```

Here is the full code:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.init();
            new Controller(model);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Model {

    private ArrayList<TableData> tableDataArrayList;

    public Model(){
        tableDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void init(){
        tableDataArrayList.add(new TableData(1, "One"));
        tableDataArrayList.add(new TableData(2, "Two"));
    }

    public ArrayList<TableData> getTableData(){
        return tableDataArrayList;
    }

    public void finish(){
        for(int x = 0; x < tableDataArrayList.size(); x++){
            System.out.println("Int value: " + tableDataArrayList.get(x).getNumberValue() + " String value: " + tableDataArrayList.get(x).getStringValue());
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller {

    Model model;
    MainGUI view;

    public Controller(Model model){
        this.model = model;
        view = new MainGUI(this, this.model);
        view.initGUI();
    }

    public void finish(){
        model.finish();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class MainGUI {

    Controller controller;
    Model model;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel mainContainer;
    private JButton bFinish;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPaneTable;
    private JTable jTable;
    TableModel tableModel;
    ArrayList<TableData> tableDataArrayList;

    public MainGUI(Controller controller, Model model){
        this.controller = controller;
        this.model = model;
        tableDataArrayList = model.getTableData();
    }

    public void initGUI(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainContainer = new JPanel();
        tableModel = new TableModel(model);
        jTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        bFinish = new JButton("Finish");
        bFinish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                controller.finish();
            }
        });
        jScrollPaneTable = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPaneTable.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1800, 400));
        jScrollPaneTable.getViewport().add(jTable);
        mainContainer.add(jScrollPaneTable);
        mainContainer.add(bFinish);
        mainFrame.add(mainContainer);
        mainFrame.setTitle("Tester");
        mainFrame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
        //Exit window on close
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Pack up JFrame
        mainFrame.pack();

        //Put Jframe in center
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //This will set window to full stream
        //mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        //Set frame visible
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    ArrayList<TableData> data;
    String[] colNames = {"Int", "String"};

    public TableModel(Model model){
        this.data = model.getTableData();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return colNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
        TableData specData = data.get(rowIndex);
        switch (colIndex){
            case 0:
                return specData.getNumberValue();
            case 1:
                return specData.getStringValue();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        TableData specData = data.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex){
            case 0:
                specData.setNumberValue(Integer.parseInt(aValue.toString()));
                break;
            case 1:
                specData.setStringValue(aValue.toString());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class TableData {

    private int numberValue;
    private String stringValue;

    public TableData(int numberValue, String stringValue){
        this.numberValue = numberValue;
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public void setNumberValue(int x){
        numberValue = x;
    }

    public int getNumberValue(){
        return numberValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String s){
        stringValue = s;
    }

    public String getStringValue(){
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what `setValueAt` does?

Comment: Don't call your class "TableModel". "TableModel" is the interface name of the model used for a JTable. Your model names should be more descriptive.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "I just don't understand how AbstractTableModel updates the ArrayList in the model class. while it gets the ArrayList from the Model, it never calls a method to tell the model to update the ArrayList values."  The code doesn't have to.  Your table model copies the `TableData` instances (instance addresses).  So, when the table model is updated, the `ArrayList` is automatically updated,

Comment: @MadProgrammer My understanding is setValueAt sets the value of the ArrayList that the TableModel has, but that is not the same ArrayList that the Model contains (at least that is what I think, which I think is wrong but I just don't know why)

Comment: @camickr Sorry bad choice of a class name, I was pulling this from a project I'm working on and was just trying to reproduce it in a much simpler way and didn't put much thought into it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc So the TableModel copies the TableData instances, and when changes are made updates the ArrayList, but why is the ArrayList in the Model class updated? Isn't the ArrayList in the TableModel an instance variable of the TableModel at this point which to me means that changes made here won't be reflected to the ArrayList in the Model class.

Comment: You ran an experiment.  You saw that the `TableData` instances were updated.  They're updated because you passed the `TableData` instances to the `JTable` model.  The `ArrayList` is just another container for the `TableData` instances.

Comment: *"but that is not the same ArrayList that the Model contains"* - Why isn't it

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc and @MadProgrammer, I think I am confused by looking at ArrayList as being a variable, where really it is just a holder of, in this case, 2 instances of TableData. So when one of the instances of TableData are changed, it doesn't really change the ArrayList itself, but the TableData object. When this object is then called by the Model class it is reading the TableData object reflecting the changes made by the TableModel. Where I got confused is thinking that `this.data = model.getTableData();` was making a new ArrayList with new objects. Does that sound correct?